# Showing $\frac{ \int^{b}_{a} (n-x^{2})^{(n-2)/2}dx}{\int^{\sqrt{n}}_{-\sqrt{n}} (n-x^{2})^{(n-2)/2}dx}$ converges to Gaussian.

Tags: calculus, analysis

I was reading the paper "Geometry of Differential Space" by McKean ([see here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2959482?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents))where the following was asserted that for $-\sqrt{n} < a < b < \sqrt{n}$ we have  $$\frac{ \int^{b}_{a} (n-x^{2})^{(n-2)/2}dx}{\int^{\sqrt{n}}_{-\sqrt{n}} (n-x^{2})^{(n-2)/2}dx} = \frac{ \int^{b}_{a} (1-x^{2}/n)^{(n-2)/2}dx}{\int^{\sqrt{n}}_{-\sqrt{n}} (1-x^{2}/n)^{(n-2)/2}dx} \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{b}_{a} e^{-x^{2}}dx$$

as $n \to \infty$.

I was wondering how one could see this?

Comment: Note that $$
\left( {1 - \frac{{x^2 }}{n}} \right)^{\frac{{n - 2}}{2}}  = \exp \left( {\frac{{n - 2}}{2}\log \left( {1 - \frac{{x^2 }}{n}} \right)} \right) \le \exp \left( { - \frac{{n - 2}}{{2n}}x^2 } \right) \le \exp \left( { - \frac{1}{6}x^2 } \right)
$$ for $n\geq 3$ and $$
\left( {1 - \frac{{x^2 }}{n}} \right)^{\frac{{n - 2}}{2}}  \to e^{ - \frac{{x^2 }}{2}} 
$$ as $n\to +\infty$. Do you know the dominated convergence theorem? The final result should be the integral of $e^{-x^2/2}$ and not $e^{-x^2}$ though.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that.

Comment: After @Gary's comments, I think (and hope) that I made it simpler.

Comment: You actually have the connection to the uniform marginal density of the first coordinate of the sphere in your answer. It was quite helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(n-x^2\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\,dx=n^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\,\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}} $$
$$\int_{-\sqrt n}^{+\sqrt n}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\,dx= \sqrt {n \pi}\,\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}$$
$$\frac {\int\left(n-x^2\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\,dx } {\int_{-\sqrt n}^{+\sqrt n}\left(n-x^2\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\,dx }=\frac 1{\sqrt{n\pi }} \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}\,\int \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}} \,dx$$
$$\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k n^{-k} \binom{\frac{n-2}{2}}{k}x^{2k}$$

When $n \to \infty$
$$\frac 1{\sqrt{n\pi }} \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2 \pi }
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\quad \to \quad \color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}}$$
$$n^{-k} \binom{\frac{n-2}{2}}{k}=\frac{2^{-k}}{\Gamma (k+1)}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\implies \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\quad \to \quad \color{red}{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}$$

So
$$\frac {\int_a^b\left(n-x^2\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\,dx } {\int_{-\sqrt n}^{+\sqrt n}\left(n-x^2\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\,dx }\quad \to \quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\int_a^b e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\tag 1$$

**Edit**

I wonder if we could make a better approximation using asymptotics and write that, for large $n$,
$$\frac {\int_a^b\left(n-x^2\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\,dx } {\int_{-\sqrt n}^{+\sqrt n}\left(n-x^2\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\,dx }\sim \frac{4 n-1}{8 \sqrt{n(n-2) }} \left(\text{erf}\left(b \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(a\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}}\right)\right)\tag 2$$

Trying for $a=0$, $b=2$ and a few values of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{exact}  & (2) \\
 100 & 0.478070 & 0.479774 \\
 200 & 0.477657 & 0.478506 \\
 300 & 0.477521 & 0.478086 \\
 400 & 0.477453 & 0.477876 \\
 500 & 0.477412 & 0.477751 \\
 600 & 0.477385 & 0.477667 \\
 700 & 0.477366 & 0.477607 \\
 800 & 0.477351 & 0.477563 \\
 900 & 0.477340 & 0.477528 \\
 1000 & 0.477331 & 0.477500 \\
 2000 & 0.477290 & 0.477375 \\
 3000 & 0.477277 & 0.477333 \\
 4000 & 0.477270 & 0.477312 \\
 5000 & 0.477266 & 0.477300 \\
 6000 & 0.477263 & 0.477292 \\
 7000 & 0.477261 & 0.477286 \\
 8000 & 0.477260 & 0.477281 \\
 9000 & 0.477259 & 0.477278 \\
 10000 & 0.477258 & 0.477275
\end{array}
\right)$$ while $(1)$ gives $0.477250$.

Comment: Deducing that the limit is $\exp(-x^2/2)$ from the first few terms of a power series is rather non-rigorous. It could be the Maclaurin series of $\exp(-x^2/2)+x^{20}$ as well. Using the hypergeometric function just makes things more complicated and confusing for the OP. The problem is a simple exercise for the use of the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: I actually don't see why $$\int_{-\sqrt n}^{+\sqrt n}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\,dx= \sqrt {n \pi}\,\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}$$, could you expand on that?